# button group bootstrap is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

i create a table with some information with a radio button, now the radio button is not working as a radio button because it is allowing to select both bbutton at the same time. This is the code for radio button ---

```
<tr class="helloo btn-sm">
                    <td >Hello Information</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
                            <button id="allowbtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Allow</button>
                            <button id="blockbtn" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Block</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

this is my javascript code ---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#allowbtn').on('click', function () {
            var url = '/manage/block';
            $.get(url, function (e) {

            });
            console.log('click');
            $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
            $(this).removeClass('btn-default');
            alert("block");
        });
    });

</script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.btn-group').button();
</script>
```

i want that if the allow button is selected it will turn green, which is working but when i select the block button, the allow button should return to it's default position. Which is not working. Can anyone kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: give to all of them the same name.

Comment: Where is your code for `#blockbtn`'s click?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#blockbtn').on('click', function () {
                var url = '/manage/block';
                $.get(url, function (e) {

                });
                console.log('click');
                $(this).addClass('btn-danger');
                $(this).removeClass('btn-default');
                alert("block");
            });
        });

    </script>

Answer (score 0):

Try putting button() inside $(document).ready().

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // init code
    ...
    // put it here!
    $('.btn-group').button();
    ...
    // other code
})
```

Comment: @ChristoferHansen
Considering what I saw in your response to Patel I would say that the problem is not buttongroup itself, but your classes. In handling clicks you do for both buttons: add class btn-danger and remove class btn-default. This means that after you click both buttons both have the same classes (which style the button?). The solution would be: if user clicks #allowbtn remove class btn-danger and add btn-default on #blockbtn. If user clicks #blockbtn remove class btn-danger and add class btn-default on #allowbtn. Please let me know if this is the error so I can update the answer.